# How to execute sh file from jenkins running on windows

Tags: shell, jenkins

Cygwin installed in my windows and able to execute the sh file using cmd prompt.
same Cygwin plugin has been installed in jenkins which also running in windows.
I created a job in jenkins build step->execute shell command I am giving the command as **sh /cygdrive/d/539707/data/getchanges/gymBuild.sh** while executing the job I am facing below exception.

NOTE 1: In Jenkins/configuration/ under shell I didn't mention any path

> workspace] $ sh -xe
>   D:\539707\tomcat-7.0.12\temp\hudson4624102689815543789.sh FATAL:
>   command execution failed java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sh"
>   (in directory "C:\Users\539707.jenkins\jobs\Test_Gym\workspace"):
>   CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified  at
>   java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)  at
>   hudson.Proc$LocalProc.(Proc.java:244)   at
>   hudson.Proc$LocalProc.(Proc.java:216)   at
>   hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:815)   at
>   hudson.plugins.cygpath.CygpathLauncherDecorator$1.launch(CygpathLauncherDecorator.java:66)
>     at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:381)     at
>   hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:95)
>     at
>   hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:64)
>     at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
>     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:782)
>     at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)  at
>   hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)   at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
>     at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)  at
>   hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)   at
>   hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
>     at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410) Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the
>   file specified    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.ProcessImpl.(ProcessImpl.java:385)    at
>   java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:136)     at
>   java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)  ... 16 more
>   Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
>
> Finished: FAILURE

NOTE 2: In Jenkins/configuration/ under shell I mention C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe

After that below is the output

> $ C:\cygwin\bin\cygpath -w C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe [workspace] $
>   C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -xe
>   D:\539707\tomcat-7.0.12\temp\hudson4745164988293910592.sh
>   /usr/bin/mintty: unknown option '-x' Try '--help' for more
>   information. Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
>
> Finished: FAILURE

Kindly suggest How to execute sh file from jenkins running on windows

Comment: mintty is not a shell, it is a terminal emulator. as a shell you have to specify path to your_cygwin_home\bin\bash.exe. And take a look at [Cygpath Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Cygpath+Plugin), it might be related to your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the solution: Shell executable path to cygwin_home\bin\sh and in jenkins build step->execute shell command give the file name ex *.sh or clear Shell executable path and  in jenkins build step->execute windows batch command sh path*.sh

Answer (score 1):

For each windows slave you can do the following to add cygwin to path assuming that your slave has cygwin installed already

- Jenkins - Manage Jenkins - Manage Nodes
- node - Configure
- Environment variables : list of key-value pairs
- add:   name: PATH  value: ${PATH};path-to-cygwin\bin

E.g.,  name: PATH value: ${PATH};d:\tools\cygwin\bin

Comment: Nope I'm wrong.  One node does this and another fails.  The only way that I know to make this work is: modify system env to include cygwin/bin on path, restart box to ensure system user which executes services takes the change